tls: handshake failure in kubernetes pod
I'm trying to stand up a basic Kubernetes cluster and I'm running into an error with TLS. Anytime a pod tries to access an https site it gets some kind of TLS handshake error. Terraform for example gets the following error:
"Error: validating provider credentials: retrieving caller identity from STS: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, exceeded maximum number of attempts, 5, https response error StatusCode: 0, RequestID: , request send failed, Post "https://sts.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/": remote error: tls: handshake failure"
While a busybox pod using wget gets this error:
"Connecting to google.com (172.67.216.51:443)
wget: note: TLS certificate validation not implemented
wget: got bad TLS record (len:7) while expecting handshake record
15 03 01 00 02 02 28
wget: error getting response: Connection reset by peer"
My environment is a Proxmox VE system that is running an Ubuntu 20.0.4 server which in turn is running kubernetes via k3sup. For my network the VM runs on a VLAN and everything runs through my OPNSense router.
I can ping google.com just fine, nslookup also returns an IP address without issue. I have also tried Centos 9 instead of ubuntu, kubeadm with Calico and then kubeadm with flannel. I don't see anything being blocked in my OPNSense firewall either. I have played around with lowering the MTU on several of the network interfaces. (Currently the VMs root is 1500 and the others are 1450)
I feel like I've tried almost everything I can think of but I can't get it to work.
